# Installation apps for clients

Tags: ios

I want to run the .ipa on customer devices without upload the app to the app store .
I collected the UDID's and I added them and I run it via iTunes.
Is their an easier way and without using the iTunes ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) is not a bad choice, you can just give them .ipa and send out email.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use http://www.diawi.com/

1) you just need to provide .ipa file to application
 
2) It will process afer that you need to press upload button
3) once upload is done Diawi will give you a web url
 
4) You can send this url to your client
 
5) client just need to open this url in safari browser and download the application.

Comment: it is an easy way. I liked it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question: do you have a regular $99 Apple Developer license, or a $299 Enterprise license ?

If you have the latter, then you can build the .ipa file, put the .plist file on your website, and simply have a button to let your users download and install their app directly on their device.

```
function onInstall()
{
    window.location = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.YourWebsite.com/YourApp.plist";
}

<div id="divDownloadButton" onclick="onInstall()">
    Tap here to download Mikes iPad app
</div>
```

There's a few hoops to jump through to get to this stage, but we use this process to distribute our in-house app to our users, without the need to collect any UDIDs.

Comment: this solution works also with the 99$ developer license (but need to manually add the UDID to the account first)... but that may break Apple's terms of uses